# R: combining matrices each time a row from one matrix with all rows in another matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have 2 matrices (`expmat` and `mat`).
    Lets say `expmat` is

```
 [1,]   -1   -1   -1   -1   -1
 [2,]    1   -1   -1   -1   -1
 [3,]   -1    1   -1   -1   -1
 [4,]    1    1   -1   -1   -1
 [5,]   -1   -1    1   -1   -1
 [6,]    1   -1    1   -1   -1
 [7,]   -1    1    1   -1   -1
 [8,]    1    1    1   -1   -1
```

and `mat` is

```
[1,]   -2   -2   -2   -2   -2
[2,]    2   -2   -2   -2   -2
[3,]   -2    2   -2   -2   -2
[4,]    2    2   -2   -2   -2
[5,]   -2   -2    2   -2   -2
[6,]    2   -2    2   -2   -2
[7,]   -2    2    2   -2   -2
```

I would like to create a loop when in each cycle I join one row from `expmat`         to all the rows in mat so that at the end 8 matrices are created and in each     matrix first 5 column are exactly the same (row from `expmat`) and other columns     changes since they come from mat. For example, first 2 matrices of the example     given will look as

```
Matrix1
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2   -2   -2   -2   -2
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1    2   -2   -2   -2   -2
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2    2   -2   -2   -2
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1    2    2   -2   -2   -2
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2   -2    2   -2   -2
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1    2   -2    2   -2   -2
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2    2    2   -2   -2

Matrix 2
1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2   -2   -2   -2   -2
1   -1   -1   -1   -1    2   -2   -2   -2   -2
1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2    2   -2   -2   -2
1   -1   -1   -1   -1    2    2   -2   -2   -2
1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2   -2    2   -2   -2
1   -1   -1   -1   -1    2   -2    2   -2   -2
1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2    2    2   -2   -2
```

This is what I'm doing:

```
for(row in 1:nrow(expmat)) {
for(row in 1:nrow(expmat)) {
val<-expmat[row,]
val<-as.matrix(val)
dshybrid=merge(t(val),mat, by=0, all=TRUE)
print(dshybrid)}
```

However I get instead what is needed

```
-1   -1   -1   -1   -1   -2   -2   -2   -2   -2
NA     NA     NA     NA     NA   2   -2   -2   -2   -2
NA     NA     NA     NA     NA   -2    2   -2   -2   -2
NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    2    2   -2   -2   -2
NA     NA     NA     NA     NA   -2   -2    2   -2   -2
NA     NA     NA     NA     NA    2   -2    2   -2   -2
NA     NA     NA     NA     NA   -2    2    2   -2   -2
....
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach does the trick:

```
lapply(split(expmat, row(expmat)), function(u){
  cbind(matrix(rep(u,nrow(mat)), ncol=ncol(mat), byrow=T), mat)
})
```

Basically `split` will make a list of `expmat` rows, then for each row you duplicate it 7 times and merge with `mat` matrix. This will give you the 8 desired matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each row of `expmat`, `cbind`-ing it to `mat`:

```
lapply(1:nrow(expmat), function(x) cbind(expmat[rep(x,nrow(mat)),],mat) )
```

The `rep` is needed so that the single row of `expmat` is repeated for each row of `mat` that it is being joined to. E.g., on a very simple example:

```
expmat <- matrix(1:4,nrow=2)
mat    <- matrix(5:8,nrow=2)
lapply(1:nrow(expmat), function(x) cbind(expmat[rep(x,nrow(mat)),],mat) )

#[[1]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    3    5    7
#[2,]    1    3    6    8
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    2    4    5    7
#[2,]    2    4    6    8
```